# Datepick not working in dynamic row

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have created a dynamic inputfield with a datepicker. 
The problem is that the date picker doesn't show when clicked.

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xEmJu/13/)

```
$('<input type="text" name="date" />').appendTo("table").datepicker();

<table id="dd">
</table>
```

Comment: Please put the FIDDLE link properly.

Comment: There is no fiddle provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to:

```
var $el = $('<input type="text" name="date" />');
$el.appendTo('table#dd');
$el.datepicker();
```

hope that helps.